# Search bar scope questions

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have implemented a table view search using a search bar with 4 scopes and everything is working fine.

I would like to able to filter table results when a user taps a scope button, without having to enter a search term also.Just give him the option to **filter results just by scope**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See UISearchBarDelegate searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange: